# How to grep between two lists and output key pairs of 'search_term' : 'item_found'

Tags: python

I have two lists, I want to use list1 as search terms in list2 and return both the search term and the "hit"

```
list1 = ["dog", "cat", "mouse"]

list2 = ["bigdog", "blackcat", "horse"]
```

I can find occurrences of list1 items in list2 like this:

```
def find_in_list(list1, list2):
    matches = []

    for i in list1:
        match = filter(lambda x:i in x, list2)
        matches.extend(match)

    return(matches)
```

This will output `['bigdog', 'blackcat']`, however I want to know which search term found the match in list2, and have output like this:

`{'bigdog': 'dog', 'blackcat': 'cat'}`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to get

```
list1 = ["dog", "cat", "mouse"]

list2 = ["bigdog", "blackcat", "horse"]

def find_in_list(list1, list2):
    matches = []

    for i in list1:
        match = filter(lambda x:i in x, list2)
        matches.extend(match)

    return(matches)

result = find_in_list(list1, list2)
dict_result = dict(zip(result,list1))
print(dict_result)
# Output: {'bigdog': 'dog', 'blackcat': 'cat'}
```

Comment: no because "mouse" is not in list2 so it should not be in the results.

Comment: @b3n-j4m1n You just need to apply your own function, and return the result to the zip have already edited my answer

Comment: that appears to not work if the lists are not in order, e.g.


`list1 = ["dog", "mouse", "cat", "car"]`

`list2 = ["bigdog", "blackcat", "horse", "bluecar"]`

# Output: {'bigdog': 'dog', 'blackcat': 'mouse', 'bluecar': 'cat'}

Answer (score 0):

This most straightforward way is this. Just iterate through each item, and when you see one string is in the other, just add it to the dictionary:

```
my_dict = {}
for item1 in list1:
    for item2 in list2:
        if item1 in item2:
            my_dict[item2] = item1
print(my_dict)
```

This is what was printed:

```
$ python dict_words.py 
{'bigdog': 'dog', 'blackcat': 'cat'}
```